# Drawflow: Change Connection Orientation

Tags: css

Using this plugin: **Drawflow**

I see that the connections between nodes are made from Left to Right or vice versa, how can I make these connections example from Top to bottom Etc?

Comment: In case someone wonders where the plugin is: github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow